# Syntax error: Unexpected token in js file on compilation

Tags: javascript, compiler-errors

**Error code:**

```
class App extends Component {


    let memos = {
         date: new Date(),
         text: 'I hope you enjoy learning React!'
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>You have no plans yet </td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
}
```

**The error:**

> Unexpected token at:

```
let memos = ...
//  ^ here
```

---

I'm just started to learn react and I caught an error.
What exactly it is?

Comment: You should start by learning ES6. :)

Answer (score 1):

The code :

```
let memos = {
    date: new Date(),
    text: 'I hope you enjoy learning React!'
}
```

should be wrapped in the constructor (or some other method), it can't be just hanging there inside the class itself:

```
constructor() {
    let memos = {
        date: new Date(),
        text: 'I hope you enjoy learning React!'
    };
}
```

and probably you should replace `let memos = ...` with `this.memos = ...` if you want `memos` to be accessible within other methods.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use `let`, `const` or `var` in the `class`. In ES2015 you can have either `static` methods or properties or methods which will go to the `prototype`. 
So, to initialize the property of the class, you should add it to the constructor.

```
class Person {
    constructor(name){
      this.name = name;
      this.createdAd = new Date();
    }
}

let bob = new Person('Bob');
bob.name // 'Bob'
```